# if you buy two seats on a flight will you be able to bring on twice the carry-on luggage?

Tags: airlines, hand-luggage

Normally you're limited to one carry on item and one personal item on a plane. But if you bought two seats for yourself would you be able to bring two personal items and two carry on items on the plane?

Comment: Often no. Which airline are we talking about here?

Comment: American Airlines is the one I had in mind, but it seems like this could be a strategy for consideration for other airlines as well.

Comment: I distinctively remember reading that the allowance is per passenger and not per ticket on some airline conditions of carriage but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: RyanAir explicitly says no. United explicitly says yes. This is an airline-by-airline thing.